# Deleting all words in MS word file except bold and italic in the terminal command

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal

I have a big MS word file. I want to delete all words in the file except the bold and italic using terminal command. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

None of the standard utilities serve this exact purpose.

You'll want to custom develop a small script/program to accomplish the task. You could use for example Python, Perl or similar to create the program.